# How can I install Oracle/SUN Java JDK in Debian Linux?

Tags: linux

I found instructions to install Java with apt-get, it worked fine until I got screen where it asks to press ok button. Well I'm on SSH connection, so mouse is not working, so how am I supposed to press this ok button? I tried to press enter, space and randomly pressing keys on keyboard, but nothing helps. Is there any way to continue from this ok screen with SSH connection?

[image]

http://orkus.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/howto-install-suns-java-6-on-debain-lenny/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try scrolling down through all the licence text? If holding the down arrow key doesn't suffice, a tab at the end should highlight the `Ok`, and then you can press `Enter`.

Comment: I actually managed to get pass this by pressing arrow keys and then enter. It didn't require reading whole license.